# Using of "fit" in meaning of "matched" about couple / partner

Tags: word-usage, verbs, transitivity

Is it ok to use "fit" in meaning of "matched" about couple / partner?

For example: I think that they fit (=they match).

In addition, in the same topic, is it correct to use these verbs (fit and match) as intransitive verbs? and then I should not add something after the verb, such as: they fit each other etc.

Comment: In what context?  If you're talking about how well they seem matched as a couple (similar interests, happy together, etc.) then you *could* use "fit" and almost certainly be understood, but it would sound odd.  It's not an expression most native speakers would use.  "They **are well-matched / well-suited**"  is much more common.  The word "fit" when used about living creatures much more often refers to *physical* condition than social/relational condition,

Comment: Apropos intransitivity, **match**, by its nature ("match what?") is always transitive, even though the "what"  may be implicit:  "Yes, your shirt and tie match [one another].  In contexts where **fit** refers to suitability, the "what"  is also often, even usually, implicit:  "that nut won't fit [that bolt], it's metric".

Comment: Is the focus of your question the transitivity of the verb, or whether the word **fit** is typically used to describe a couple's compatibility?

Comment: Both. But first of all about the using of "fit".

Comment: Intransitive ***fit*** in the sense of *match, go together well* is just about credible, but idiomatically it's not very common. For your specific context nearly all native speakers would more likely say *I think they **are a good fit*** (assuming the word ***fit*** must be included; overall, *I think they are a good **match*** is probably more common).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I seem to recall hearing _they fit together nicely_ or _they really fit together_ about a couple. I realise the addition of _together_ alters the expression, but does that really sound outlandish?

Comment: oerkelens: I suspect that those phrases would indicate either that the speaker doesn't quite have a perfect grasp of the language OR that sexual intercourse is a covert subtext, the reason being that "fit"  almost always refers to *physically* fitting, even if metaphorically.  The example from employment is such a metaphor:  someone is "the best fit"  because they're regarded impersonally as a kind of peg whose skill and personality characteristics appear to be of the perfect size and shape for the hole for which they were interviewed.

Comment: @oerkelens: I think MMacD's idea that ***fit*** used of a couple significantly alludes to the physicality of genital "plumbing" is a bit of a stretch. But the NGram for [they are a good match/fit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+are+a+good+match%2Cthey+are+a+good+fit&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20are%20a%20good%20match%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20are%20a%20good%20fit%3B%2Cc0) could misleadingly imply they're used equally. Both effectively mean the same thing if "they" are *people* - but not if they're, say, *shoes*.

Comment: ...Note that if I exclude potentially "inanimate" references by searching for [**we** are a good match/fit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+are+a+good+match%2Cwe+are+a+good+fit&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwe%20are%20a%20good%20match%3B%2Cc0), **fit** doesn't occur often enough to chart.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interestingly, if I add [we fit together](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+are+a+good+match%2Cwe+are+a+good+fit%2C+we+fit+together&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwe%20are%20a%20good%20match%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20fit%20together%3B%2Cc0) to your ngram, it's more common than the other two. Of course, this is about _fit_ used as a verb, not a noun, but the _question_ is about _fit_ used as a verb.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice question.

**Usage of *fit* for couples/partners**

Personally, I would use other words or phrases to describe a couple who seem to be made for each other. One of which would be the phrase I used right there in the preceding sentence:

> I think they **are made for each other**.

Other than that, I might probably look at describing what it is that makes me think they are well-matched:

> I think they **share a lot of interests**.
>
> I think they **complement each other**. 
>   *(e.g. they have opposite traits and they seem like these traits will bring out the best of both)*
>
> I think they **are on the same wavelength**. 
>   *(e.g. they have the same form of black humour)*

**Why not *fit*?**

I've seen *fit* used in the context of *best fit* when it comes to recruitment. And in those scenarios, it is often the case that there is a list of job requirements on the one hand, and a list of candidate who satisfy one or more of those job requirements - the one who satisfies the most is said to have the *best fit*.

I would shy away from using *fit* to describe relationships because it implies that someone has a similar list of requirements that the partners are being assessed against, and to me, such a connotation seems... cold.

Comment: 1+^ Thank you for your answer. For me it's important to talk about match, I can use synonyms for match but "I think they are made for each other" it's already far from the original meaning and it makes it with another meaning:)

Comment: OK, if you're looking for something closer to *match*, then you might consider *They are well-suited for each other*.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it, but it's a little bit long for my need. May be you have an example of intransitive verb?

Comment: "*They gel together*" ?

Comment: Will it work in such context (relationship)? http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gel_2

Answer (score 1):

Many of the comments, as well as an answer given, seem to focus exclusively on *fit* used as a noun. However, the question is about the sentence

> (I think that) they fit.

*Fit* is clearly a verb in that sentence, and while the use of *fit* on its own like that does seem a bit off to me, like to (semingly) most people, adding *together* somehow makes it sound much better.

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+are+a+good+match%2Cwe+are+a+good+fit%2C+we+fit+together&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwe%20are%20a%20good%20match%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20fit%20together%3B%2Cc0) seems to agree that *we fit together* is more common than *we are a match*. *We are a fit* doesn't seem to be used at all. (I'm using *we* to exclude inanimate objects - thank you [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124374/using-of-fit-in-meaning-of-matched-about-couple-partner?noredirect=1#comment251343_124374) )

So to answer the question:

Yes, you can use *fit* intransitively (although one could argue that the object (eachother) is implied).

Yes, it's a good idea to add something to it, and I propose *together*:

> They fit together.